# How to pause AutoRotation in cocos2d (AutoRotation using UIViewController)?

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

My game app is LandScape & AutoRotation using UIViewController.

And login view(scene) is UIView, not scene.

I wanted "Portrait Mode" login view. and did work.

When I use UITextField... AutoRotation make some problem

Only Keyboard is Landscape Mode...

So I need to non-autorotation in LogIn View. (After Login, autoratation is needed)

How can I pause AutoRotation?

Answer (score 0):

you may want to implement "shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation" and lock orientation to potrait

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {

     return interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait; 
}
```